# Anchor text going outside div

Tags: html, css

I have a product div and an anchor tag that displays it's name. It's text is going outside the div. How to control this text?

```css
.element {
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 345px;
  min-width: 221.46px !important;
  max-width: 230.46px !important;
}

.element img {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.element:hover {
  border: 1px solid #fe9c00;
}

.element button i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.element button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #fe9c00;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 19px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  width: 88%;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: -11px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.element:hover button {
  margin-top: -40px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.info-pro {
  position: absolute
}

.element:hover img {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.element a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.element span {
  color: #fe9c00
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="element">
    <img src="../../../../../uploads/store/products/{{ $product->product_image1 }}" width="200" height="200" alt="img1" />
    <button><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>ADD To Card</button>
    <div class="info-pro">
      <a href="#">Asus DUAL-GTX1070-O8G Graphics Card</a>
      <span>Rs 59,849.00</span>
      <p>In stock</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have provided a single sniplet. Can anyone please help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have removed

```
.info-pro {
  position: absolute
}
```

```css
.element {
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 345px;
  min-width: 221.46px !important;
  max-width: 230.46px !important;
}

.element img {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.element:hover {
  border: 1px solid #fe9c00;
}

.element button i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.element button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #fe9c00;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 19px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  width: 88%;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: -11px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.element:hover button {
  margin-top: -40px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.element:hover img {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.element a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.element span {
  color: #fe9c00
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="element">
    <img src="../../../../../uploads/store/products/{{ $product->product_image1 }}" width="200" height="200" alt="img1" />
    <button><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>ADD To Card</button>
    <div class="info-pro">
      <a href="#">Asus DUAL-GTX1070-O8G Graphics Card</a>
      <span>Rs 59,849.00</span>
      <p>In stock</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using position absolute you need to add `position:relative` to the parent (**.element**) to make it position according to it and not other parent.

```css
.element {
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 345px;
    min-width: 221.46px !important;
    max-width: 230.46px !important;
    position: relative;
}
.element img {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
 .element:hover {
    border: 1px solid #fe9c00;
}
.element button i {margin-right: 10px;}
.element button {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: #fe9c00;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 19px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    width: 88%;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -11px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    
}
.element:hover button {
    margin-top: -40px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.info-pro {position: absolute}
 .element:hover img {margin-top: 0px;}
.element a {display: block;text-decoration: none;font-size: 13px;}
.element span {color: #fe9c00}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="element">
    <img src="../../../../../uploads/store/products/{{ $product->product_image1 }}" width="200" height="200" alt="img1" />
    <button><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>ADD To Card</button>
    <div class="info-pro">
      <a href="#">Asus DUAL-GTX1070-O8G Graphics Card</a>
      <span>Rs 59,849.00</span>
      <p>In stock</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Change `width` to `inherit` or try giving small size to width of your button.
2. Give `position:relative;` to `.element`

   ```
   .element button {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: #fe9c00;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 19px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -11px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
   }

   .element {
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 345px;
    min-width: 221.46px !important;
    max-width: 230.46px !important;
    position: relative;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:absolute` in `.info-pro`. `position:absolute` removes the element from the flow of the document, that's why it can't "see" other elements

```css
.element {
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 345px;
  min-width: 221.46px !important;
  max-width: 230.46px !important;
}

.element img {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.element:hover {
  border: 1px solid #fe9c00;
}

.element button i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.element button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #fe9c00;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 19px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  width: 88%;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: -11px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.element:hover button {
  margin-top: -40px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.element:hover img {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.element a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.element span {
  color: #fe9c00
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="element">
    <img src="../../../../../uploads/store/products/{{ $product->product_image1 }}" width="200" height="200" alt="img1" />
    <button><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>ADD To Card</button>
    <div class="info-pro">
      <a href="#">Asus DUAL-GTX1070-O8G Graphics Card</a>
      <span>Rs 59,849.00</span>
      <p>In stock</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```